# What does this phrase from “Independence” mean?

Tags: legacy-ship

On page 4 of *Independence*, the first book of the *Legacy Ship* trilogy, is the following passage:

> He dozed off after setting the nav computer to autopilot. The ship would swivel one hundred eighty halfway out to Sangre and automatically start the decel burn. And he’d need to be awake and alert for the actual delivery — planetary re-entry on an old rickety freighter like the Magdalena Issachar was like trying to screw a discount mutated whore on Rigel Three while half-drunk — it required a certain amount of concentration, but not so much concentration that you realized with horror what the hell you were doing.

What's "screw a discount mutated whore"? What’s "Rigel Three"?

Comment: Rigel Three: the 3rd planet in the Rigel system (the system of the star Rigel).

Comment: @DavidW - I've added the actual (e-)book quote. I think OP was likely re-typing it from a physical copy.

Answer (score 11):

This is really more of an English Language question than a Sci-Fi & Fantasy one, but there's a tiny bit of SF-specific language involved.

> [It] was like trying to screw a discount mutated whore on Rigel Three while half-drunk

Firstly, understand that this is a *simile*: the writer is comparing the challenges of steering the freighter to some other activity.

Most of the description of the activity is real-world English slang:

- "screw" is one of many slang words for "have sex with"
- "whore" means "prostitute", i.e. someone you can pay to have sex with
- "discount" here just means "cheap", with the implication that you get what you pay for - so, not a very *good* prostitute
- "while half-drunk": if you have had some alcohol, having sex may be harder, but you might be more eager to go through with it; as Shakespeare put it "Lechery, sir, [drink] provokes, and unprovokes; it provokes the desire, but it takes away the performance"

That leaves two pieces that only make sense within the SF context:

- "mutated" likely refers to [the common SF meaning of "mutant"](https://sfdictionary.com/view/72/mutant) as someone "with freakish or exceptional anatomy, abilities, etc"; it goes along with "discount" to suggest that the prostitute in question isn't very attractive
- "Rigel Three" is a planet: ["Rigel" is a real star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigel), and "Rigel 3" is how astronomers would refer to its third planet, if it had one. It's not really relevant to the simile, its just colour to add to the atmosphere.

So to re-word:

> [It] was like trying to have sex with an unattractive prostitute under the influence of alcohol

Comment: Whore is more derogatory than prostitute.

Comment: Although, funnily enough, it's being reclaimed by some people, who make the distinction that prostitutes have sex for money while a whore may just enjoy having sex.

Answer (score 3):

The author (writing from the perspective of our main character, Danny) is using a [simile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile) to describe the process of landing a ship as old and poorly maintained as the Magdalena Issachar onto a planetary surface.

In short, he compares it to having sex with a very ugly prostitute from Rigel, a planetary system frequently visited in the books. You need to be paying a fair amount of concentration to the job at hand (e.g. landing/having sex), while at the same time not looking too closely at the bigger picture (e.g. you're in a controlled crash/you're having sex with someone very ugly).